# PetitParser and Parentheses

Tags: flutter, dart, hl7-fhir, petitparser

Sorry, I ran into another question about using PetitParser. I've figured out my recursive issues, but now I have a problem with parentheses. If I need to be able to parse the following two expressions:

1. '(use = "official").empty()'
2. '(( 5 + 5 ) * 5) + 5'

I've tried doing something like the following:

```
final expression = (char('(') & any().starGreedy(char(')')).flatten() & char(')')).map((value) => ParenthesesParser(value));
```

But that doesnt' work on the first expression.
If I try this:

```
final expression = (char('(') & any().starLazy(char(')')).flatten() & char(')')).map((value) => ParenthesesParser(value));
```

It doesn't work on the second expression. Any suggestions on how to parse both?

Comment: If the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67361125/82303) helped, please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think neither of the parsers does what you want: The first parser, the greedy one with `starGreedy`, will consume up to the last closing parenthesis. The second parser, the lazy one with `starLazy`, will consume up to the first closing parenthesis.

To parse a balanced parenthesis you need recursion, so that each opening parenthesis is followed by a matching closing one:

```dart
final inner = undefined();
final parser = char('(') & inner.star().flatten() & char(')');
inner.set(parser | pattern('^)'));
```

In the snippet above, the inner parser is recursively trying to either parse another parenthesis pair, or otherwise it simply consumes any character that is not a closing parenthesis.